# How do I transfer saved data to a new iPhone?

Tags: ios, applications, data

I want to upgrade to a new iPhone but have apps that store data, such as inventory, car maintenance data, etc…  I don't want to lose this information when I upgrade.

How do I transfer this saved data when I set up my new iPhone?

Answer (score 2):

### Use iTunes

You can use iTunes to backup the device, then restore the backup to the new iPhone.

1. Connect your old iPhone to iTunes.
2. Click **File** → **Devices** → **Back up**.
3. Once the backup has finished, unplug your old iPhone and plug in the new one.
4. When asked to set up the iPhone, choose **Restore from this backup**, and select your backup from the list.

   If you don't do it during first set up, go to **File** → **Devices** → **Restore from Back up**.

[image]

### Use iCloud

Instead of iTunes, you can use iCloud Backup to backup and restore your information.

1. On your old iPhone, go to **Settings** → **iCloud** → **Backup & Storage** and press **Back Up Now**.
2. On your new iPhone, during the setup process, select **Restore from iCloud Backup**.

   If you don't do it during the setup process, you can erase your device through **Settings** → **General** → **Reset** → **Erase All Content and Settings**, then the setup process will restart.

   [image]
   [image]